# How to run sql scripts during sbt build

Tags: database, scala, sbt

I'm building my scala application with sbt. How can I run .sql script file during the build?

It is possible to run scripts with ant like this

```
<target name = "createTables">
<sql
  classpathref="classpath"
    driver="${database_driver_class_name}"
  url="${database_url}"
  userid="${user}"
  password="${password}"
   src="createTables.sql"/>
```

Can I do the same with sbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with an sbt plugin such as FlyWay (https://flywaydb.org/documentation/sbt/)